# Why is iPhone bottom mic volume different different with headphones plugged in vs not?

Tags: ios, iphone, core-audio, avaudiosession

I am creating an app that uses iPhone bottom mic for recording with or
without headphones plugged in. My issue is that the volume for
recording with headphones plugged in is much lower than recording with
headphones not plugged in.

Is there a setting/configuration I need to add for when headphones are
plugged in, so that recording is same volume as without headphones. I've tried adjusting AVAudioSession.inputGain, but it has same effect.

Answer (score 1):

A few things come to mind depending on the intent of your application.

1. I have found that using the **Front** microphone is better for recording if the user is not going to be holding the device close to their face (i.e. phone call).
2. Configuring the data source polar pattern & orientation can also have a dramatic impact depending on the context of use. Check out the class reference for **AVAudioSessionDataSourceDescription**.
3. If you are willing to to use Audio Units for your input processing, enabling the **Voice Processing IO** effect unit can dramatically improve both the quality and volume of the capture. See example below.

   ```
   AudioComponentDescription desc;
   desc.componentType         = kAudioUnitType_Output;
   desc.componentSubType      = kAudioUnitSubType_VoiceProcessingIO;
   desc.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
   desc.componentFlags        = 0;
   desc.componentFlagsMask    = 0;
   ```

Comment: I had the category mode set to AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement. Setting it to AVAudioSessionModeDefault fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the category mode set to AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement. Setting it to AVAudioSessionModeDefault fixed my issue.